# How to stretch an image when user scrolls in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to stretch an image when the user scrolls.

```
Container(
 child: Image.asset(
  'assets/appHeader.png',
   fit: BoxFit.cover,
   width: size.width,
   height: 170,
 ),
)
```

This image is at the top of the page and when user scrolls up I want to stretch the image.
It will be like the stretch in SliverAppBar. I am pretty new to flutter so I don't know much about animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, i am create this by using FlexibleSpaceBar.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 200.0,
              floating: false,
              //pinned: true, if you need to show appBar.
              pinned: false,

              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  centerTitle: true,
                  title: Text("Image Text(optional)",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      )),
                  background: Image.network(
                    "https://miro.medium.com/max/700/1*_nCC_uFDVYas8uYa9m6fQQ.jpeg",
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )
                  /*-------Your Image here--------*/
                  /* Image.asset(
          'assets/appHeader.png',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          width: size.width,
          height: 170,
          ),*/
                  ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Your screen data"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I dont want the header to appear when I scroll to the bottom.

Comment: ok, i will update by answer as per your requirement.

Comment: another question. How can I put another container over it?? as like we do it in stack

Comment: means.. 
you need add container in body.or any other place.
i am not get it, "How can I put another container over it?? as like we do it in stack"'

Comment: I want to add container over the SliverAppBar

Comment: if you want to container over SilverAppBar,then place Scaffold inside of Container(for this situation).

Answer (score 1):

this answer update regarding(that you ask in comment)(this applicable only for this situation that we discuss in question).

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Scaffold(
              //same code that above write
              )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can I add a stack then??